# Documentation Tools: Don't put web URL in user package docs

Tags: documentation, workbench

I am exploring the Workbench documentation tools for the first time and one of the difficulties I encountered was that every generated (compiled) documentation page includes weblinks.  These point to reference.wolfram.com, where there is of course nothing about my package.

[image]

- How can I disable these links?
- Can I set a custom base URL so the link goes to my own website instead of Wolfram's?

(At this moment I just want to disable these, but setting a base URL seemed like a reasonable question to ask at the same time.)

Comment: Link to W Community version: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/956614

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no way to control the generation of the URL dropdown.  Wolfram Support confirmed this.

A practical solution that worked for me (and which was suggested by several people here on SE) is to post-process the generated notebooks and remove the unwanted parts.

```
NBRemoveURL[nb_] :=
    ReplaceAll[
      nb,
      {start___, Delimiter, "\"Copy web URL\"" :> _, "\"Go to web URL\"" :> _} :> {start}
    ]

nb = Import["file.nb"];
Export["file.nb", NBRemoveURL[nb]]
```

Remember to save/`Export` the documentation notebooks with the earliest version of Mathematica that your package supports.  Otherwise the front end may complain about potential compatibility problems when the notebook is viewed.

Do read this before starting with post-processing:

- [Exporting notebooks inserts unwanted $CellContext. Workaround?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132458/12)