# Exporting notebooks inserts unwanted $CellContext. Workaround?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

Let's import a notebook:

```
nb = ImportString["Notebook[{},TrackCellChangeTimes->False]", "NB"]
(* Notebook[{}, TrackCellChangeTimes -> False] *)
```

All is well so far.  Now let's re-export it:

```
ExportString[nb, "NB"]
```

Now the output contains

```
$CellContext`TrackCellChangeTimes -> False
```

instead of

```
TrackCellChangeTimes -> False
```

This happens with every valid notebook or cell option that doesn't already have a corresponding symbol in the `` System` `` context, and thus `Import` creates it in `` Global` `` instead.

**Why does this happen?  What's a reasonable workaround?**

Notes:

- I need the notebooks exported with full cache information, so I cannot export them as a plain expression.
- `NotebookSave` suffers from the same problem.
- The problem goes away if I use `"TrackCellChangeTimes"` (a string) instead of `TrackCellChangeTimes`.

  However, cycling such a notebook expression through `NotebookPut` and `NotebookGet` "removes" the quotes and converts the string to a symbol again.  Thus I do not know how to get strings for such options when importing a notebook.
- I am using `Import`/`Export` to [post-process notebooks created by the documentation tools and fix things](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132292/12).  The unwanted `$CellContext` causes subtle breakage that I did not even notice until now.

Comment: Should I delete my answer and make it a duplicate? [Programming scripts to create and modify stylesheets](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102189/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Please don't delete, the duplicate is too long. This answer is clear an simple.  Let's keep it as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR;

You can redirect unknown symbols to `` System` `` which will be stripped later:

```
Block[{$Context = "System`"},
 nb = ImportString["Notebook[{},TrackCellChangeTimes->False]", "NB"]
]
```

---

### Digging in boxes' (cell expressions)* typesetting

*in opposite to expressions typesetting e.g.: `` Global`symbol `` -> `RowBox[{"symbol"}]`

That is acutally quite important part of typsetting. So when will the context be stripped? When will `` $CellContext` `` appear? Here is a small test:

```
sample = {
 {#, #, #2, "System`"},
 {#, #2, #2, "System`"},
 {#, "System`", #2},
 {#, #2, #2},
 {#, #2, #2, "System`", #}
 } & @@@ {{"JLink`", "Global`"}, {"Global`", "JLink`"}, 
    {"System`", "JLink`"}, {"FrontEnd`", "Global`"}
 } //  Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

```
 result = Block[{$Context = #2, $ContextPath = {##3}}, Reap[
       Module[{str},
        str = 
         ExportString[
          Notebook[{}, Symbol[# <> "TrackCellChangeTimes"] -> False], 
          "NB"];
        str = StringToStream[str];
        Sow[{#, #2, {##3}, Find[str, "TrackCellChangeTimes"]}];
        Close[str];
        ]][[-1, 1, 1]]
     ] & @@@   sample;
```

```
result // SortBy[Last] //  TableForm[#, TableAlignments -> Right, 
   TableHeadings -> {None, Style[#, Bold, 15] & /@ {"symbol's context", "$Context",  "$ContextPath", "exported string"}}] &
```

[image]

So the rules seem to be as follows:

#### `Which[`

- Symbol's context is `` System` ``?

  Leave only the symbol name.
- Symbol's context is the same as current `$Context`?

  Use `` $CellContext`symbolName ``
- Is symbol's context `` Global` ``,`` FrontEnd` `` or any FrontEnd related?

  Leave only the symbol name.
- True

  Use symbol's full name.

#### `]`

Comment: It was of course WholeGroupCellOpener for me too.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've conducted a little investigation, have to go now. Tell me if I've missed something.