# Once[…, "location"] adds $CellContext` to all global symbols

Tags: symbols, contexts, persistence

For certain persistence locations, such as `"Notebook"` or `"FrontEndSession"`, `Once` adds `` $CellContext` `` to all `` Global` `` symbols, e.g.

```
Once[x, "Notebook"]
```

after the second evaluation (when the persistent object has been created) will only give

```
$CellContext`x
```

and not just `x`.

I'm sure there's a good reason for this (avoiding collisions), but I see two problems at the moment:

1. The obvious problem that all names of symbols are now changed.
2. In my case, in place of `x` I have an expression that returns a fairly long result, and the addition of `` $CellContext` `` to each symbol name blows up the stored result unnecessarily.

**How can I get `Once` not to add `` $CellContext` `` to every symbol name?**

I have already tried some tricks such as `` Block[{$Context = "System`"}, …] `` (as in [Exporting notebooks inserts unwanted $CellContext. Workaround?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132459)), but `Once` appears to be treatment-resistant.

(I'm aware that one can access and change the content of the corresponding `PersistentObject` and in this way manually remove the added context, but this seems like a risky brute force solution to me.)

Comment: i think maybe you should report this as a bug to wolfram support? it certainly seems like `Once[...]` should produce the same output on each subsequent evaluation as it did for its first evaluation—that's its whole deal! In the meantime...hmmm. Maybe you could remove the `$CellContext`s forcibly after evaluation as a workaround? Might defeat the point of `Once` though...

Comment: @thorimur Yeah, as mentioned I'm sure you can try to find the `PersistentObject` after creation (although I'm not sure how the hashes are created) and then change the value inside `PersistentObject[…]["Value"]`. Seems risky to me.
I think the main problem is that `Once` is hard to control — compare how in the answer I referenced there was indeed a solution with `Block` that doesn't work here.

Comment: Just out of interest I tried to crack the hashes. I can't quite figure them out, but i'm fairly sure it's what you get when you take the default "Expression" type hash of some expression (not sure which) as an 8-byte bytearray, then convert it to base 64 and trim leading zeros. The hashes use the characters 0-9, a-z, A-Z, "-", and "_" for a total of 64 characters to encode the resulting base 64 number—not sure exactly how, either, but hashes always seem to be between 10 and 11 characters, and `Log[64, (16*16)^8]` is 10 and 2/3.

Comment: I can confirm that this is still a problem with Mathematica 14. It also caused me no end of grief.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, only a workaround:

```
undoCellContext[expr_] := Module[{ccSymbols, rules},
  ccSymbols = 
   Cases[expr, _Symbol, \[Infinity]] // DeleteDuplicates // 
    Select[StringStartsQ["$CellContext`"]@*ToString];
  rules = (# -> Symbol["Global`"<>SymbolName[#]]) & /@ ccSymbols;
  expr /. rules
  ]

Once[...,"Notebook"] // undoCellContext
```

As an optimization, when `LeafCount[expr]` is suitably large, `undoCellContext` could switch from building a list and deleting duplicates to populating a HashSet within the delayed rule given to Cases.

It would also perhaps help if `undoCellContext` held the expression, and the replacement symbols, unevaluated until it was done with it.

We could "Fix" Once on versions where it's misbehavinbg:

```
If[$VersionNumber<=14.,
  Unprotect[Once];
  Once`Private`$overridden = True;
  Once[expr__,"Notebook"] := Block[{Once`Private`$overridden = False},
    Once[expr, "Notebook"] // undoCellContext
  ] /; Once`Private`$overridden
  Protect[Once];
]
```

For reference, `Once` is not guilty. The underlying problem is that `PersistentObject[...,"Notebook"]["Value"]` converts `Global</code> symbols to <code>$CellContext` on readout.